# Does SPDY compress all my contents on default?

Tags: http, networking, compression, gzip, spdy

I just don't get it: I just use a normal SPDY server (node-spdy), I haven't defined any special headers like `Content-Encoding` or such things and I don't compress my contents by hand.

**My Question:** When I want to compress my contents (not just the headers), do I have to compress everything on my own by hand? Or does SPDY gzip my contents automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, SPDY does not compress the payload data, just the headers. You have to compress the payload yourself.

See https://groups.google.com/d/topic/spdy-dev/HXkhL6TASN4/discussion for why SPDY data compression was removed.

Comment: to help me to understand, if I compress the payload data, the web browser will then decompress it even though we are using SPDY?